# c# winforms control loop method in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I got this method in winforms c# which work perfect . But i can't figure it out that how to make this method exactly same for asp.net webpages . 
Any little help would be appreciated .

```
public static void rat(Form x)
    {
        Form myForm = x;
        foreach (Control c in myForm.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Name != "ctn" && !(c is Label))
            {
                c.Enabled = !(c.Enabled);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the below two lines. Since it's a `ASP.NET` application you will expect a `Page` instance instead of a `Form` instance. Cause every `ASP.NET` webform inherits from `Page` base class likewise in `Winform` every form inherits from `Form` base class.

```
public static void rat(Page x)
    {
        Page myPage = x;
```

Considering your webform name is `webform1`, you can do this

```
public static void rat(Page x)
    {
        webform1 myForm = (webform1)x;
        foreach (Control c in myForm.Controls)
        {
            if (c.Name != "ctn" && !(c is Label))
            {
                ((Label)c).Enabled = !((Label)c).Enabled);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that . it don't work . The enabled method is not available there

Comment: @Brendom, those `Enable` are control properties and must be present for every control. Try it properly.

Comment: 'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Enabled' and no extension method 'Enabled' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) this is what i get on ENABLED

Comment: @Brendom, common; before you try the enable property you have to cast to exact control. I bet the posted code doesn't work in winform as well. see edit after sometime.

Comment: this code work perfect in WINFORMSC# . waiting for your edit